# Style analyzer for WPF/Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am looking for a utility that will go through all XAML files in a project and locate defined styles that aren't being used anywhere.

does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such tool, as much as I aware of.

You can use simple *Find* of `VisualStudio`, or [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx), or [XamlPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms742398%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (which is free).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up writing a simple tool that goes through the XAML files, parses out the resources and then finds uses by looking for it being used in a StaticResource markup extension. It's not smart about it - (it assumes if you declare a resource called "MyResource" that any {StaticResource MyResource} instances are the same) but it works and is capable of scanning tens-of-thousands of lines of xaml in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If the style is in the same File [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) does a pretty good job at showing unused styles, converter, etc... by graying them out a bit.
There is a 30-day trial version available.

That's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I see unused namespaces and such greyed out, is there a trick to get the resources to become greyed out?

Comment: @rhooligan: There is no special setting you have to make that i'm aware of. I added a screenshot from visual studio how it should look. Does it also not work when you add an empty stlye?

Comment: Be careful with Resharper: it does not understand when a style is defined in XAML and then used from code.  It marks the style as unused in this scenario.

Comment: I didn't see that.  Maybe I need to reboot my computer.

Comment: I did not care for re-Sharper.  It slowed the whole environment down. Maybe it's time to upgrade to 16GB of ram.

Answer (score 1):

I did a small application for this purpose for Silverlight styles. It should be surely adaptable for WPF. The source code and binary may be found here:

[Removing unused styles from Silverlight projects](http://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/removing-unused-styles-from-silverlight-projects)

Rgds,

Bruno